# How to display pre-checked checkboxes inside iterator in Struts 2

Tags: struts2, checkboxlist

I need to iterate through `List<String>`, each element has `s:checkbox`.

I have defined one list in Action layer to keep selected elements.

Using my code I can submit my form and capture selected values in action layer. But,   some of the checkboxes must be pre-checked. I cannot display pre- checked status when loading the page.

`Value1` contains list of String objects.

`functionCheckBoxList` -  The list I have defined to keep checked element

While loading, I added some element to `functionCheckBoxList` that belongs to `Value1`.

But still does not show pre-checked status in the page.

```
<s:iterator value="value1" var ="functionName">
        <s:checkbox  fieldValue="%{#functionName}" name="functionCheckBoxList" 
            value="%{#functionName}"  theme="simple" >
         </s:checkbox>
</s:iterator>
```

Note: I know how to do it using `s:checkboxlist` but can't here as I need special format in the iteration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i could find a solution for my problem, i would like to share it with everyone.

```
<s:iterator value="value1" var ="functionName">
     <s:checkbox  fieldValue="%{#functionName}" name="functionCheckBoxList"  
     value="%{#functionName in functionCheckBoxList}" theme="simple" >
     </s:checkbox>
</s:iterator>
```